# Twilio-Video in React-native using Expo: use "module:react-native-twilio-video-webrtc"

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo, webrtc

I want to use Twilio-Video in react-native project. At the moment we are using Expo and Expo Go to start project. I found two packages: **React Native WebRTC** and **react-native-twilio-video-webrtc**. I am not react-native developer, so this is basically new for me. I tried to follow some kind of guides from github. Both packages are not working with my configuration. I tried a lot of staff. If you ever tried and used it before can you help me to write down some kind of steps. which are workable. Basically I am getting this error. I can show you part of my code if needed

[image]

I tried to install these packages. installed successfully, but project did not start. I tried expo prebuild and modified content of android directory result was same